# html5 + css3 slider animations problems with chrome

Tags: html, css

Here is the CSS3 and the HTML for a carrousel

http://jsfiddle.net/5P7Gu/

```
#slider {
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    clip:rect(0px,900px,140px,0px);
    overflow:hidden;
}
#insideSlider{
    animation: move1 20s ease 2s infinite   ; 
   -moz-animation: move1 20s ease 2s infinite  ; 
   -webkit-animation: move1 20s ease 2s infinite  ; 
}
#insideSlider:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
    -animation-play-state:paused;
}


@keyframes move1 {
0% {transform:translateX(0px);}
10% {transform:translateX(-155px);}
20% {transform:translateX(-310px);}
30% {transform:translateX(-465px);}
40% {transform:translateX(-620px);}
50% {transform:translateX(-775px);}
60% {transform:translateX(-930px);}
70% {transform:translateX(-1085px);}
80% {transform:translateX(-1240px);}
90% {transform:translateX(-1395px);}
100% {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);}
} 

@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);}
10% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-155px);}
20% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-310px);}
30% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-465px);}
40% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-620px);}
50% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-775px);}
60% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-930px);}
70% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-1085px);}
80% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-1240px);}
90% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-1395px);}
100% {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);}
}  
@-moz-keyframes move1 {
0% {-moz-transform:translateX(0px);}
10% {-moz-transform:translateX(-155px);}
20% {-moz-transform:translateX(-310px);}
30% {-moz-transform:translateX(-465px);}
40% {-moz-transform:translateX(-620px);}
50% {-moz-transform:translateX(-775px);}
60% {-moz-transform:translateX(-930px);}
70% {-moz-transform:translateX(-1085px);}
80% {-moz-transform:translateX(-1240px);}
90% {-moz-transform:translateX(-1395px);}
100% {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);}
}  


.vignette {
    display:inline-block;
    width:130px;
    margin:10px;
}

.imageVignette {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    position:relative;
}

.imageVignette:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2,1.2);
    transition:0.3s;
}

.vignette:hover .description{
    bottom:10px;
    transition:0.3s;
}


.description {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-20px;
    display:block;  
    width:130px;
    height:30px;
    transition:0.3s;
}



.description .detail {
    font-size:12px;
    position:absolute;bottom:0px;
    height:25px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:100%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #AAA;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="insideSlider">

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <div class="vignette">
                <img  class="imageVignette" src="http://placehold.it/128x128"  />
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <a href="#">hello1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  




    </div>                             
</div>
```

I have 2 problems I cannot solve

1) on chrome, when you rollover sometimes it is ALL scrambles and moves to left all the slider in a crazy way !

2) the .detail rollover works only BEFORE animation begins.

Any clue on this pure css3 slider is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code just a little. You can have a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5P7Gu/3/).

1.) On chrome i had the same problem you described above: The weird movement of the boxes only happened before the animation started though. So i removed the delay of your CSS animation and it worked fine. I'm still not sure why this happened, need to have another look at it.

```
animation: move1 20s ease infinite; /* Removed delay due to weird behaviour */
-moz-animation: move1 20s ease infinite; 
-webkit-animation: move1 20s ease infinite;
```

2.) You had some weird positioning going on in your CSS. I cleaned up some of them and applied the scaling on hover to the parent.

You used inline-block, but forgot to remove the trailing whitespace (http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). So i added HTML comments to get rid of the whitespace. Feel free to remove them and use "float: left;" instead of "inline-block".

Last thing i did was using percentage values for the widths, so your carousel is a bit more responsive.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to change the transition values inside your keyframe animation to percentage values.